# Não está trocando a pagina quando troca na paginação

Tags: c#, pagedlist

Quando estou tentando ir para a pagina 2, ele mostra o site carregando, porém só me trás as primeiras informações da pagina 1 da minha paginação.
Minha Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        IList<Abastecimento> abastecimento = dao.Lista();
        page = 1;
        int NumRegistro = 10;
        int NumPag = (page ?? 1);
        return View(abastecimento.ToPagedList(NumPag, NumRegistro));
    }
```

Minha View:

```
 Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

Comment: Você tem que passar o número da página para o método `Lista()` e fazer com que o método retorne apenas a quantidade de itens referente àquela página. Neste seu código, o método `Lista()` traz tudo do banco e faz a paginação no `controller`. Quando você tiver milhares de registros, uma página demorará demais para ser exibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu troquei o ActionResult por um ViewResult.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        IList<Abastecimento> abastecimento = dao.Lista();
        page = 1;
        int NumRegistro = 10;
        int NumPag = (page ?? 1);
        return View(abastecimento.ToPagedList(NumPag, NumRegistro));
    }
```

Por:

```
public ViewResult Index(int? page)
    {
        IList<Abastecimento> abastecimento = dao.Lista();
        page = 1;
        int NumRegistro = 10;
        int NumPag = (page ?? 1);
        return View(abastecimento.ToPagedList(NumPag, NumRegistro));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remova essa linha do seu código

```
page = 1;
```

Vai funcionar. Você está colocando sempre o valor 1 na variável.

Comment: Eu retirei e mesmo assim não troca de pagina.

Comment: Acredito que o erro está na montagem do seu link de paginação. Observe que você cria o parametro a ser passado, porém não alimenta ele com valores:

Comment: @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))

Falta adicionar algo aqui: new { page = XXXXXX }))

Comment: Para resolver eu coloquei o ViewResult no lugar do ActionResult